# Receiving an exception in overloaded operator >> section

Tags: c++, ios, class, overloading, operator-keyword

So I've overloaded an operator ">>" for my class MyString. It was supposed to read information from text file to a custom-made string, however I'm getting an exception when I'm trying to fill string char by char. Text.txt contains simply "xyz"

Main.cpp:

```
#include "MyString.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
//TO-DO 1 CharArr for all
int main() {

    MyString NewString;
    ifstream In("Text.txt");
    In >> NewString;

    cout << NewString << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Constructors:

```
MyString::MyString() {
    StringLength = 0;
    Pointer = nullptr;
}

MyString::MyString(const char* String) {
    for (int i = 0; String[i]; i++)
    StringLength++;
    Pointer = new char[StringLength + 1];
    char *Source = (char *)String;
    char *Destination = (char *)Pointer;
    for (int i = 0; i < StringLength + 1; i++)
    Destination[i] = Source[i];
}
```

Operator:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &In, MyString &String) {
    int FileStringLength = 0;
    char Character;
    if (String.Pointer != nullptr)
        delete[] String.Pointer;
    while (In.get(Character) && Character != '\n')
        FileStringLength++;
    if (FileStringLength < 1000 && FileStringLength != 0) {
        String.StringLength = FileStringLength;
        In.clear(), In.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        for (int i = 0; In.get(Character) && Character != '\n'; i++)
                String.Pointer[i] = Character; // I get an exception here
    }
    else if (!FileStringLength) {
        cout << "File is empty." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "File contains too many characters." << endl;
    }

    return In;
};
```

Comment: After `delete` where is there space to put `Character`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (String.Pointer != nullptr)
    delete[] String.Pointer;
```

freed the storage that

```
String.Pointer[i] = Character; // I get an exception here
```

was going to use.

## Solution:

Don't `delete[]` the storage. Instead write over it until the storage is full, then allocate a new, larger buffer for storage, copy the old buffer into the new buffer, and then free the old buffer.